# svn+ssh, pageant and AUC administrator privilidges

Tags: svn, ssh, uac, administrator, pageant

I'm facing a strange problem using svn+ssh and pageant.
My system (W7 x64) is configured using maximum UAC protection.

Case 1
- Starting pageant and adding my keys.
- Accessing svn archives using svn+ssh from a command window works fine.

Case 2
- Starting pageant with administrator privs. and adding my keys
- Accessing svn archives using svn+ssh from a command window running with administrator privs. works fine.

Case 3
- Starting pageant and adding my keys
- Accessing svn archives using svn+ssh from a command window running with administrator privs FAILES.
- The other way around fails as well.

My conclusion is that the pageant must execute with the same admin privs as the client trying to use it. This causes me some problems since I'm using svn+ssh from different admin. privs.

Any ideas of how to get around this problem are appreciated.

/Lars

Comment: Where are the keys stored? If they're stored in HKCU (current user portion of registry), then you have to access them using the same logon as you used to create them. Otherwise you will need to export them from the registry and import for whichever user needs them.